# Using ERB when injecting HTML into the DOM using jQuery/CoffeeScript

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, heroku, coffeescript

I am inserting the following HTML into the DOM from within in AJAX success callback. The AJAX call provides `data`, which contains the fields used below. For every `player1` and `player2` there is an associated image saved in assets/images as `"#{first_name}_#{last_name}"`. How can I replace the `data` fields in the HTML below with ERB? Specifically, I would like to use rails' `image_tag` so that the image's url includes the alpha-numeric code (digest) that is appended to the image url in the production environment (Heroku).

Thanks!

```
    getFullMatchupHTML = (data) ->
        fullMatchupHtml = 
        '<div class="row">' +
            '<div id="matchupID" data-matchupid=' + data.matchup.id + '></div>' +
            '<div id="mpcontainer" class="">' +
                '<div id="mp1" class="span5 mp">' +
                    '<h3>' + data.player1.first_name + ' ' + data.player1.last_name + '</h3>' +
                    '<h4>' + data.player1OpponentTeamName + '</h4>' +
                    '<div id="mpimage1" class="mpimage">' +
                        '<img src="/assets/' + data.player1.first_name + '_' + data.player1.last_name + '.jpg" alt="' + data.player1.first_name + '_' + data.player1.last_name + '" class= "playerpic" >' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div id="mp2" class="span5 mp">' +
                    '<h3>' + data.player2.first_name + ' ' + data.player2.last_name + '</h3>' +
                    '<h4>' + data.player2OpponentTeamName + '</h4>' +
                    '<div id="mpimage2" class="mpimage">' +
                        '<img src="/assets/' + data.player2.first_name + '_' + data.player2.last_name + '.jpg" alt="' + data.player2.first_name + '_' + data.player2.last_name + '" class= "playerpic" >' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</br>' +
        '<div class="row" id="num-votes-row" class="hiddenVoteRow">' +
            '<div class="">' +
                '<div id="mpts1" class="span5">' +
                    '<h2>' + data.ptsplayer1 + '</h2>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div id="mpts2" class="span5">' +
                    '<h2>' + data.ptsplayer2 + '</h2>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try placing `format.js` at the bottom of your controller action to respond with a `js.erb` view. In that view you can simply put the javascript you want to run when the server responds to your ajax call. So if your action is `edit` for example, then create a view called `edit.js.erb` in the appropriate view folder.

Comment: That makes sense, but how would I handle AJAX callbacks? Is there a way to do it using the code I have above for now, even if using format.js is the better method down the road?

Comment: One other question: if the controller action is run from a link/button on the 'home.html.erb' page, and the action is a custom action called 'UpdatePoints', should I put my JS in 'UpdatePoints.js.coffee.erb'? Will I be able to edit items in the DOM that were loaded in home.html.erb? Thanks again!

Comment: When a rails form with `remote: true` is submitted, the controller will receive the request and then if `format.js` is used then the controller will look for a `UpdatePoints.js.erb` file

Comment: Gotcha. So can I then use Javascript/Coffeescript in `UpdatePoints.js.coffee.erb` to make changes to the html in `home.html.erb`? And I can use ERB in `UpdatePoints.js.coffee.erb` included in quotes, like `"<%= image_url(@player.image_name) %>"`? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Yeah, you should be able to use erb in the file. I haven't personally used coffeescript, but I looked around and it seems like by naming the file `UpdatePoints.js.coffee` it will allow erb despite the lack of an erb file extension.